# The grammatical role of "rich" in the following sentence

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

What is the grammatical role of "rich" in the following sentence and what does mean it? (also why it uses the comma?)

> In the Pacific Northwest, the high level of precipitation ensures
>   **rich**, green plant life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Rich" is an adjective.  It modifies "plant life."

There is a comma between "rich" and "green" because both adjectives modify "plant life" and we separate consecutive adjectives with commas.

The meaning of "rich" there is

> Existing in plentiful quantities; abundant.
>   https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rich

Answer (score 2):

It is an adjective, part of the noun phrase "rich, green plant life".

The comma is optional in a string of adjectives like this. When I read it aloud, because of the comma I pause briefly, and begin a new prosodic contour for "green plant life", which has the effect of putting more emphasis on "rich" than if I read it through as "rich green plant life".